# Prevent content expanding grid item vertically

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I don't want the content of my grid items been able to expand it. I was able to prevent this horizontally by setting the grid `min-width: 0`. Tried the same with `min-height: 0` but it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.productGallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.productGallery:before {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.featuredImage {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 5 / 5;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryList {
  grid-area: 1 / 5 / 5 / 5;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="productGallery">
  <div class="featuredImage">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="galleryList">

  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` will work when you set the height property to some value. `height: 100px` for ex.

Comment: That works, but I want the grid items to be responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.productGallery:before` style. This is what causing the extra space at bottom.

**Edit:**
If you are looking to make the gid a square always, update your `.productGallery:before` class as. Please check [this](https://medium.com/cloudaper/how-to-create-a-flexible-square-grid-with-css-grid-layout-ea48baf038f3) blog for reference.

```
.productGallery:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
}
```

```css
.productGallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.productGallery:before {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    grid-row: 1 / 1;
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
}  
.featuredImage {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 5 / 5;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryList {
  grid-area: 1 / 5 / 5 / 5;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="productGallery">
  <div class="featuredImage">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  </div>
  <div class="galleryList">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, you're right, but that's what making the grid a square. Any other solution?

Comment: @JuliánPera I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: That worked, thank you. I'm still having the main issue with the vertical overflow expanding the grid.

Comment: @JuliánPera how should your actual UI look like?